# Consolidate NGINX config for my VueJS and Flask App

Tags: nginx, server, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm working on deploying my VueJS and Flask app. After watching few tutorials I came to the NginX configuration below. It works, but it's getting long. Is there a  way I can consolidate the location endpoints to something like this location /*?

I've tried - location /*, location *.

```
server {
  listen $PORT;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }

  location /ping {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_redirect      default;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }

  location /query_usdot {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_redirect      default;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }

    location /subscribe {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_redirect      default;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nginx documentation [states](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location):

> location can either be defined by a prefix string, or by a regular expression.

To join this three location blocks you can use this regexp:

```
location ~ ^/(?:ping|query_usdot|subscribe) {
   ...
}
```